# Java standalone app with JPA + Hibernate (or similar) and Apache Derby embedded DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, derby

I want to create a Java standalone Java application that will use the Apache Derby Embedded DB.

I want to use JPA since I'm quite familiar with it and probably over Hibernate ( but others are welcome if it is to get easier).

Is there any example that uses JPA over Hibernate over a Derby embedded db? I was searching around but I can't find any useful example code. I would like something like a tutorial that will tell which libs I need to add in my classpath, which are the essential files and what I need to do.

Comment: What's wrong with the official quickstart: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/getstart/

Comment: @DaDaDom The official quickstart does not contain anything about JPA or Hibernate. I have already checked it :)

Comment: Well, you stated that you already knew JPA, so I thought that you only needed the Derby-side of things. It can be used like any other database within JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: OK! This is a useful answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Maven for your build, you can use the [derby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin), which I wrote and is available on GitHub and via Maven Central. It will take care of starting and stopping the database for you before your tests.

You can check:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731178/creating-temporary-database-that-works-across-maven-test-phases/15089028#15089028) for my answer to a similar question
- [Here](http://nigel-eke.com/unit-integration-testing-rest-services/rest-test-add-integration-tests/) for a sample REST application which uses Derby and has tests